# Error in download thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I am developing an application which is downloading a series of zip files.

It works fine, but sometimes it crashes and I can see the following error in the project navigator:

```
Thread 5 WebThread: EXC_??? (11)(code=0,subcode=0x0)
```

Any ideas? I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` to download the files.

Comment: What is ur device and device OS?  Asihttp request gave me un specified crash in iPod +ios6 combo

Comment: In my simulator IOS 6.1

Comment: I migrated to AFnetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: i guess you should go in for try catch and reload in case of failure

Comment: Please run the app and let it crash and then in the debugger console type `bt` to get a stacktrace and then post that with your question.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using ASIHTTPRequest you can try for Async Request. The following code gives you details about downloading images just replace that with your zip url link

This is another method for downloading option. Having more  thread function in an app will cause performance issue.

```
-(IBAction)startdownload
{
for (int i=0; i<[downloadarray count]; i++)   //download array have url links
{
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[downloadarray objectAtIndex:i]];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:URL];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
if([data length] > 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
{
//make your image here from data.
UIImage *imag = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
NSArray *array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imgstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSString *pngfilepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sample%@.png",docDir,imgstr];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(imag)];
[data1 writeToFile:pngfilepath atomically:YES];
}
else if ([data length] == 0 && [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"])
{
NSLog(@"No Data!");
 }
else if (![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",error] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]){
NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
}
}];

}

 -(IBAction)viewfile
{
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pngfilepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",documentsDirectory];
NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:pngfilepath error:&error];
  for (int i=0; i<[filePathsArray count]; i++){
NSString *pngfilepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",documentsDirectory,    [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
[arr addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pngfilepath]];
}
myimageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[arr objectAtIndex:0]]; //Here   myimageview is UIImageView

}
```

Hope it Helps !!!

Comment: @vishnu That is because of some memory problems in your app

Answer (score 0):

Can you track exception for more details?

replace your main.m with this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = -1;
        @try {
            retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([FRAppDelegate class]));
        }
        @catch (NSException* exception) {
            NSLog(@"Uncaught exception: %@", exception.description);
            NSLog(@"Stack trace: %@", [exception callStackSymbols]);
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

I'm also using `ASIHTTPRequest` for downloading and it works fine for me. I'm using `ASINetworkQueue`.